# Can you factor out a common divisor when finding $\gcd(a,b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I am given to find a $\gcd$ and I can see a common divisor, can I divide it to make the problem smaller? if so what do I do with the common divisor?

In the case of $\gcd(2780,785)$ I can see the $5$ is a common divisor, and let $\gcd(556,157)=a$ what will be the $\gcd(2780,785)$?

Comment: What are you currently thinking?

Comment: Hint: 157 is a prime number

Comment: If your question is if you can "factor out" the five ahead of time, yes absolutely you can.  $\gcd(ak,bk)=k\gcd(a,b)$ (so long as $k$ is a positive integer)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right: if $k$ divides $a$ and $b$ then  $\gcd(a,b)=k\gcd(a/k,b/k)$.

Another property of $\gcd$ which could be useful here is
that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-kb,b)$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Hence
$$\gcd(2780,785)=5\gcd(556,157)=5\gcd(556-3\cdot 157,157)=5\gcd(85,157).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Under my interpretation of the question, the OP is asking for clarification on the first step taken here and is asking whether the step $\gcd(2780,785)=5\gcd(556,157)$ is at all justified.  "*If I am given to find a gcd and I can see a common divisor, can I divide it to make the problem smaller? if so what do I do with the common divisor?*"  This does not answer the stated question.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the comment. I edited my answer. Is it more useful now?

Answer (score 0):

There are several strategies you can use.

1) You can use of course that $\gcd(ca,cb)=c\gcd(a,b)$ for everyy $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$.

2) Write $A = yB + C$ using the euclidean divion. Since you are looking for something dividing both $A$ and $B$ as you can see it must divide $C$. So you can say that $\gcd(A,B)=gcd(B,C)$.

Let's try to apply these two rules.

Applying $1)$ we get $\gcd(2780,556)=5\gcd(556,157)$.

I can't see another easy step so we can try to use euclidean division and write:

$$ 556 = 157\times 3 + 85 $$

thus using rule $2)$ we get $\gcd(556,157)=\gcd(157,85)$.

Let's try again, we write

$$ 85 \times 2 -157= 13 $$

thus $\gcd(157,85)=\gcd(85,13)=1$ because $13$ is a prime number which doesn't divide 85. Combining we get 
$$\gcd(2780,556)=5\gcd(556,157)=5\gcd(157,85)=5\gcd(85,13)=5$$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks!